# Routes and subpackages in controllers

Tags: java, routes, playframework-2.1

I'm using Play 2.1 and I'm having some odd problems.

I have a subpackage `messages` in the `controllers` package with a class `i18n.java`.

My `routes` file looks like this:

```
GET     \    controllers.messages.i18n.index()
POST    \    controllers.messages.i18n.process()
```

I now have a form with the following action:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.messages.i18n.process())
```

but this gives me an error:

`value messages is not a member of object controllers.routes`

I've used subpackages before in Play 2.0.4 and it worked fine like that, can anyone spot any errors in my configuration?

The routes file doesn't complain that it can't find the controller.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The route should be `controllers.messages.routes.i18n.process()`. You can inspect the `target/scala-2.10/src_managed` directory to discover generated files.

And for information, Java coding conventions say that a class must start with an uppercase.

Comment: The class name was a copy/paste/edit fail, but this works! Thanks for the `src_managed` hint aswell

Answer (score 11):

FYI, in 2.2 it's slightly different.

routes.conf looks like:

```
GET  /admin/stuff  controllers.admin.StuffController.show()
```

in code looks like:

```
controllers.admin.routes.StuffController.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

For Play 2.4.6 Java users:

Let's say your controller (Application) and action (logout) is `com.stackoverflow.play.Application.logout()`.

To use it in your template (`*.scala.html`), you do `@com.stackoverflow.play.routes.Application.logout` (e.g., `<a href="@com.stackoverflow.play.routes.Application.logout()">`, `<form action="@com.stackoverflow.play.routes.Application.logout()" method="post">`).

Read the bottom part of this link: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaRouting