# Playframework - subpackaged controllers and routing issues

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

**System Details:**

- Arch Linux: 4.11.7-1-ARCH x64
- Oracle Java JDK: 1.8.0_131
- IntelliJ Scala plugin: 2017.1.19 (latest)
- SBT: 0.13.13 (latest)
- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.1.4
- Play Framework: 2.6.1

**Intro**

*note: I am new to play framework*

I am using the provided "play-starter" project, and with this I have created a controller that routes to various pages. This worked by using no subpackages.

Directory structure: `{root}/app/controllers/MyController`

`MyController.index()` was displayed with the routing path:

```
GET     /                        controllers.MyController.index
```

this displayed as expected, also a `POST` method I created functioned as expected.

---

**Problem:**

I attempted creating subpackages to start my project, but received errors at every turn (details below).

Browsing the [routing documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaRouting) yielded no solution (for me). I searched for similar issues, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010595/routes-and-subpackages-in-controllers) is a very similar issue, but the answer does not solve my problem.

A [blog](https://nealvs.wordpress.com/2013/03/01/play-2-0-java-controller-route-packagesfolders/) seemed to address the issue, which I attempted without success.

Error Output:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:37417,suspend=y,server=n -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/cybex/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/config/plugins/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar:/usr/share/intellij-idea-ultimate-edition/lib/idea_rt.jar xsbt.boot.Boot run
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:37417', transport: 'socket'
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/cybex/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/project
[info] Set current project to EatAloT (in build file:/home/cybex/Documents/University/Year%205/WRR301/eatalot/eatalot/)

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080

(Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] Compiling 35 Scala sources and 13 Java sources to /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/target/scala-2.12/classes...
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/conf/routes:8: type AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error] GET        /user                 controllers.User.routes.AccountController.index()
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/conf/routes:8: type AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error] GET        /user                 controllers.User.routes.AccountController.index()
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/conf/routes:8: type AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error] GET        /user                 controllers.User.routes.AccountController.index()
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/app/views/User/Account/index.scala.html:28: object AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error]         <form action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.login()" method="get">
[error]                                                ^
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/app/views/User/Account/index.scala.html:32: object AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error]         <form action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.register()" method="get">
[error]                                                ^
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/app/views/User/Account/login.scala.html:17: object AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error]         <form action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.doLogin()" method="post">
[error]                                                ^
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/app/views/User/Account/register.scala.html:16: object AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error]         <form method="post" action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.doRegister()">
[error]                                                              ^
[error] 7 errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[info] Compiling 35 Scala sources and 13 Java sources to /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/target/scala-2.12/classes...
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/conf/routes:8: type AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error] GET        /user                 controllers.User.routes.AccountController.index()
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/conf/routes:8: type AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error] GET        /user                 controllers.User.routes.AccountController.index()
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/conf/routes:8: type AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error] GET        /user                 controllers.User.routes.AccountController.index()
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/app/views/User/Account/index.scala.html:28: object AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error]         <form action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.login()" method="get">
[error]                                                ^
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/app/views/User/Account/index.scala.html:32: object AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error]         <form action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.register()" method="get">
[error]                                                ^
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/app/views/User/Account/login.scala.html:17: object AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error]         <form action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.doLogin()" method="post">
[error]                                                ^
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/app/views/User/Account/register.scala.html:16: object AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error]         <form method="post" action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.doRegister()">
[error]                                                              ^
[error] 7 errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] application - 

! @74j57k5c0 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[type AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes]
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:49)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
[info] Compiling 35 Scala sources and 13 Java sources to /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/target/scala-2.12/classes...
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/conf/routes:8: type AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error] GET        /user                 controllers.User.routes.AccountController.index()
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/conf/routes:8: type AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error] GET        /user                 controllers.User.routes.AccountController.index()
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/conf/routes:8: type AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error] GET        /user                 controllers.User.routes.AccountController.index()
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/app/views/User/Account/index.scala.html:28: object AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error]         <form action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.login()" method="get">
[error]                                                ^
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/app/views/User/Account/index.scala.html:32: object AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error]         <form action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.register()" method="get">
[error]                                                ^
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/app/views/User/Account/login.scala.html:17: object AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error]         <form action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.doLogin()" method="post">
[error]                                                ^
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/app/views/User/Account/register.scala.html:16: object AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error]         <form method="post" action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.doRegister()">
[error]                                                              ^
[error] 7 errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[info] Compiling 35 Scala sources and 13 Java sources to /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/target/scala-2.12/classes...
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/conf/routes:8: type AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error] GET        /user                 controllers.User.routes.AccountController.index()
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/conf/routes:8: type AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error] GET        /user                 controllers.User.routes.AccountController.index()
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/conf/routes:8: type AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error] GET        /user                 controllers.User.routes.AccountController.index()
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/app/views/User/Account/index.scala.html:28: object AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error]         <form action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.login()" method="get">
[error]                                                ^
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/app/views/User/Account/index.scala.html:32: object AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error]         <form action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.register()" method="get">
[error]                                                ^
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/app/views/User/Account/login.scala.html:17: object AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error]         <form action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.doLogin()" method="post">
[error]                                                ^
[error] /home/cybex/Documents/play-project/eatalot/app/views/User/Account/register.scala.html:16: object AccountController is not a member of package controllers.User.routes
[error]         <form method="post" action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.doRegister()">
[error]                                                              ^
[error] 7 errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

**Problem details:**

I created a subpackage `User`. Within this subpackage, I have one controller `AccountController`

`AccountController` has several functions, I'll use `doLogin()` for the purposes of this question

Directory structure: `{root}/app/controllers/User/AccountController`

**Suggested Solution:**

All solutions point to the same code (which results in various errors)

Each package has its own routes file. In my case, I should use `controllers.User.routes` followed by the controller name and function for the routes file

e.g.

```
POST       /user/login        controllers.User.routes.AccountController.doLogin()
```

where the directory layout is `controllers/User/AccountController` and using using this for display purposes in a view ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499078/how-to-put-play-controllers-in-an-arbitrary-sub-package)) I use

```
<form action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.doLogin()" method="post">
```

**BUT** this does not work.

---

**Extra Info:**

*{root}/app/controllers/User/AccountController*

```
package controllers.User;

import models.User;
import play.Logger;
import play.data.DynamicForm;
import play.data.FormFactory;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import views.html.User.Account.*;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class AccountController extends Controller{

    @Inject
    FormFactory formFactory;

    public Result index() {
        //...
    }

    public Result login(){
        //...
    }

    public Result doLogin(){
        //...
    }

    public Result register(){
        //...
    }

    public Result doRegister(){
        //...
    }

}
```

*{root}/conf/routes*

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# An example controller showing a sample home page
GET     /                        controllers.HomeController.index

GET        /user                 controllers.User.routes.AccountController.index()
GET        /user/register        controllers.User.routes.AccountController.register()
GET        /user/login           controllers.User.routes.AccountController.login()

##disable this an you will recieve a 403 forbidden error, the CRSF filter is used for cross site scripting prevention, use for authentication
#+ nocsrf
POST       /user/register        controllers.User.routes.AccountController.doRegister()
#+ nocsrf
POST       /user/login           controllers.User.routes.AccountController.doLogin()

# An example controller showing how to use dependency injection
GET     /count                   controllers.CountController.count
# An example controller showing how to write asynchronous code
GET     /message                 controllers.AsyncController.message

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file            controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

*{root}/app/views/User/Account/index.scala.html*

```
@(users: Set[User])

<html>
    <header>
        <title>All users in list</title>
    </header>
    <body>
        <h1>All users in list</h1>
        <br>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                <th>Cellphone</th>
            </tr>
             @for(user <- users) {
            <tr>
            <td>@user.id</td>
            <td>@user.name</td>
            <td>@user.surname</td>
            <td>@user.cellNumber</td>
            </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <br>
        <br>
        <form action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.login()" method="get">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
        <br>
        <form action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.register()" method="get">
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

*{root}/app/views/User/Account/login.scala.html*

```
@(message: String)

<html>
    <header>
        <title>Login Form</title>
    </header>
    <body>
        <h1>Login Form</h1>
        <br/>
        <label>Email:</label> <input type="email" name="edtEmail"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label>Password:</label> <input type="password" name="edtPassword"/>
        <br/>
        <label>@message</label>
        <br/>
        <form action="@controllers.User.routes.AccountController.doLogin()" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm glad your issue has been resolved. Next time, please try to share a minimal (!) case. that would make me a bit more encouraged to help out ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have been some bug, since redoing what I did any previous "tests" to get it working, has proved to resolve the issue.

A formal solution for `Play 2.6.1` project having a sub package and requiring routing to it:

Subpackage name: `User`
Subpackage Controller: `AccountController`

---

**Project App Directory Structure:**

```
app/
      controllers/ (provided)
      filters/ (provided)
      models/ 
      services/ (provided)
      views/  (provided)
```

**Controllers Directory**

```
controllers/
          User/ (sub package)
                AccountController.java
          HomeController.java (provided)
```

Account controller contains methods:

- index()
- register()
- doRegister()

**Views Directory**

```
views/
          User/
                Account/
                     index.scala.html
                     register.scala.html
          index.scala.html (provided)
```

*Note:* try to keep the same directory structure (see `User/Account/{controller function name}`)

**Routing file** entry `conf/routes` :

```
GET        /user                 controllers.User.AccountController.index
GET        /user/register        controllers.User.AccountController.register()

#disable this (below) and you will receive a 403 forbidden error, the CRSF filter is used for cross site scripting prevention, use for authentication. 
#You can apply this autentication: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017920/post-method-rendering-403-forbidden-page-instead-of-executing-post-method-code

#+ nocsrf
POST       /user/register        controllers.User.AccountController.doRegister()
```

Hopes this helps!